# how to test whether grid is empty or not in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a grid and adding elements to is in jquery like below:

```
$('#MyGrid tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="#" >' + htmlString.ID+ '</a></td></tr>');
```

before that i need to test whether this MYgrid is empty or not. how to do that with jquery.

thanks,

michaeld

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just count the rows, and if there are non, assume that your grid is empty?

```
if(!$('#MyGrid tr').length) {
    // grid is empty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:empty` selector:

```
$('#MyGrid tbody:empty').append('<tr><td><a href="#" >' + htmlString.ID+ '</a></td></tr>');
```